# Akka vs Java 7 Futures

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, future

I am trying to understand when to use [Akka Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html) and found [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/composing-futures-akka) to be a little bit more helpful than the main Akka docs. So it looks like Akka Futures do exactly the same thing as [Java 7 Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). So I ask:

- Outside the context of an actor system, what benefits do Akka Futures have over Java Futures? When to use each?
- Within the context of an actor system, why *ever* use an Akka Future? Aren't all actor-to-actor messages asynchronous, concurrent and non-blocking?

Comment: Akka's `Future` and `Promise` are more comparable to Java's `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, but you may not think it be like it is, but it do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Akka Futures implement asynchronous way of communication, while Java7 Futures implement synchronous approach. Yes they do the same thing - communication - but in quite different way.

Producer-Consumer pair can interact in two ways: synchronous and asynchronous. Synchronous way assumes the consumer has its own thread and performs a blocking operation to get next produced message, e.g. `BlockingQueue.take()`. In asynchronous approach, consumer does not own a thread, it is just an object with at least two methods: to store a message and to process it. Producer calls the store method, just like it calls `Queue.put(m)` in synchronous approach, but this method also initiates execution of the consumer's processing method on a common thread pool.

UPDT
As for the 2nd question (why ever use an Akka Future):
Future creation looks (and is) simpler than Actor's; code for a chain of Futures is more compact and more demonstrable than that of Actors.
Note however, a Future can pass only a single value (message) while an Actor can handle a sequence of messages. But sequences can be handled with [Akka Streams](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-stream-java8). So the question arise: why ever use Akka Actors? I invite more experienced developers to answer this question. Generally, I think if your task can be solved with Futures, then use Futures, else if with Streams, use Streams, else if with Akka Actors, then use Actors, else look for another framework.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei Kaigorodov (+1) - I think that addresses my first concern, regarding using Akka Futures *outside* the context of an actor system. If I understand you correcty, one should use them when you need a normal Java 7 Future, but need an *asynchronous* producer/consumer interaction. **But what about my 2nd concern?** What about using Akka Futures *inside* an actor system? If actor-to-actor messaging is already asynchronous, why ever use an Akka Future inside an actor system? Would you use them inside an actor that is communicating with, say, an external/blocking database? Thanks again!

Comment: What makes Java 7 Futures more synchronous than Akka futures then? I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of your question, I agree with Alexei Kaigorodov's answer.

For the second part of your question:

It is useful to use a `Future` internally when actor responses need to be combined in a very specific way.  For example, let's say that the `Master` actor needs to perform several blocking database queries and then aggregate their results, and so `Master` sends each query to a `Worker` and will then aggregate the responses.  If the query results can be aggregated in any order (e.g. `Master` is just summing row counts or whatever) then it makes sense for `Worker` to send its results to `Master` via a callback.  However, if the results need to be combined in a very specific order then it is easier for each `Worker` to immediately return a `Future` and for `Master` to then go about manipulating these `Futures` in the correct order.  This could be done via callbacks as well, but then `Master` would need to figure out which query result is which to put them in the correct order and it will be much more difficult to optimize the code (e.g. if the results of query1 can be immediately aggregated with the results of query2 then by using a `Future` this logic can go directly into the dispatch code where the identities of all queries is already known, whereas using a callback would require `Master` to identify the query result and also determine if it can aggregate the query with any other query results that have been returned).